# What is getVoiceMailAlphaTag() for?

Tags: android

I saw the method TelephonyManager.getVoiceMailAlphaTag() but I have no idea what it's for. The javadocs are useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations like this it always helps to [Use the source®](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java) - IMHO this is a HUGE advantage of Android over other platforms.

On GSM phones this gets down to [SIMRecords](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/uicc/SIMRecords.java).

Apparently (after some googling) alpha tag for voicemail is a name that your mobile operator uses for voicemail. If not set it defaults to "Voicemail" in english

This data (voicemail alpha tag & voicemail number) is stored inside SIM and is usually set by your operator.